# Get Place ID from ArcGIS service

Tags: arcgis-online, arcgis-rest-api, geocoding-service

Nominatim geocoder returns osm_id as a location attribute. See [this example](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim#Example)

`<result place_id="1620612" osm_type="node" osm_id="452010817">
  135, Pilkington Avenue, Wylde Green, City of Birmingham, West Midlands (county), B72, United Kingdom
</result>`

Is it possible to get place ID with ESRI geocoder? Like esri_id or place_id?

I make the following request to geocoder http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?f=pjson&outFields=%2A&text=Big+Ben

Comment: @vince I updated the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: Are you making your request to and ArcGIS Server or ArcGIS Online geocoding service?  Are you actually using ArcGIS 10.2?  What have you tried?

Comment: @PolyGeo I make the following request to geocoder http://geocode.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/World/GeocodeServer/find?f=pjson&outFields=%2A&text=Big+Ben

Answer (score 1):

In the OSM data model, a single ID makes sense because the data is all being resolved down to a single resource. In the case of the Esri geocoder, there is no single source of truth that would naturally lend itself to unique IDs — but between the scores, location, and address, you should be able to get pretty good correspondence between the two where it exists.